# "When is the next time you come to downtown"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I wanted to ask my friend when he would come to downtown again. So I came up with

> "When is the next time you come to downtown"

is this sentence grammatically correct? Should it be

> "When is the next time you will/would come downtown"

since downtown can be used as adv.

Comment: In order from least to most relaxed: "When is the next time you will come downtown?", "When's the next time you'll come downtown?", "When's the next time you'll be downtown?"

Comment: @TylerM Hi can you elaborate on what you meant by relaxed?

Comment: Relaxed = Informal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence is more grammatically correct. If you're speaking in an informal manner, you can also contract you will into you'll to make it easier to say.